# Arguments of anonymous subroutines in the BEGIN block

Tags: perl

I one source code i saw the next construction:

```
our %hash;
BEGIN {
    %hash = (
         KEY1 =>
          sub { return $_[0]->somefunc( 1, $_[2]->attr1, $_[2]->attr2 ); },
         KEY2 =>
          sub { return $_[0]->somefunc( 0, $_[2]->attr1, $_[2]->attr2 ); },
         ...
    );
}
```

What are those `$_[0]` (they are the first arg of anonymous sub) - but here are in the `BEGIN` block... so, what is its value at "compilation" phase?

The `$hash{KEY1}` get a subroutine reference, but to what subroutine?

### EDIT

Now (i hope) understand. Just dumped the content of the `%hash` with `Data::Dumper::Concise` and got the next:

```
  ...
  KEY1 => sub {
      package MyPkg;
      use warnings;
      use strict;
      return $_[0]->somefunc(1, $_[2]->attr1, $_[2]->attr2);
  },
  KEY2 => sub {
      package MyPkg;
      use warnings;
      use strict;
      return $_[0]->somefunc(0, $_[2]->attr1, $_[2]->attr2);
  },
  ...
```

So, the construction returns a reference to anonymous sub, what *when will be executed* returns the result of execution of `$_[0]->somefunc` with the supplied args.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sub {}` creates an anonymous subroutine and returns a reference to it (just as `[]` and `{}` do with arrays and hashes).

The `$_[0]`, etc., are the arguments to that sub.

So if you call `$hash{KEY1}->('foo','bar','baz')`, `$_[0]` will be 'foo'.

The fact that the anonymous sub was generated at compile time isn't relevant.